# Pressing "Home" in Vim on an Indented Line

Tags: vim, key, line

I have a bad habit of using the 'home' key to go back to the beginning of a line. As I recently started using vim I noticed that when I press the home key on a lined that is indented, it returns me to the very beginning of the line. In Notepad++ (the editor I used to use) it would return me to the beginning of the code on that line, right after the indent.

Is there some way to replicate this behavior in vim? Usually, when I'm pressing home it's in the Insert mode for me to (usually) stick a variable there.

I have `set smartindent` in my vimrc, with `set noautoindent` as a "tips" page told me to make sure to disable autoindent (although it didn't seem to be enabled in the first place - perhaps that option is extraneous.)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There are two usual ways to go to the "beginning" of a line in Vim:

- <kbd>0</kbd> (zero) go to the first column of text
- <kbd>^</kbd> go to the first non-whitespace on the line

I find that using <kbd>0</kbd><kbd>w</kbd> is usually the most convenient way for me to go to the first nonblank character on a line, it's the same number of keys as <kbd>^</kbd> and is easier to reach. (Of course, if there are no leading spaces on the line, don't press <kbd>w</kbd>.)

Comment: So, no way to do this in insert mode? I guess I should get used to swapping between the two.

Comment: I don't think there's a way; I don't use cursor movement in insert mode at all. This article might be helpful: http://www.viemu.com/a-why-vi-vim.html

Comment: @Reid - You could probably map it in one way or another (see below) - but all movement should really be done in N mode, not I.

Comment: Aha, that's true. I suppose I'll get used to it eventually. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 15):

You could remap <kbd>Home</kbd> to be the same as <kbd>^</kbd> (the docs say <kbd>Home</kbd>'s default function is equivalent to the movement command <kbd>1</kbd><kbd>|</kbd>):

```
:map <Home> ^  
:imap <Home> <Esc>^i
```

Which should make the insert mode mapping be equivalent to escaping out of insert mode, pressing <kbd>^</kbd> and then returning to insert mode. I don't know about the best method of mapping a motion command for use inside insert mode, so this may break something, but it seems to work.

As to your indentation settings, they shouldn't have an effect on movement controls, but I also think you probably would prefer to have them set differently. autoindent just keeps your current indentation for new lines (so if you place 4 spaces at the beginning of a line, after you press return your new line will also have 4 spaces placed in front of it). I don't know why you wouldn't want that, since it's pretty useful in pretty much any programming language, or even just freeform text. smartindent on the other hand implements a couple of hard-coded lightly C-ish indentation rules, like indenting after an opening {, and deindenting after a closing }, but doesn't automatically carry over indentation from previous lines. The docs recommend keeping autoindent on if you use smartindent.

However, smartindent is useless for languages that don't meet its hard-coded rules, or even actively harmful (like when it automatically removes indentation from any line starting with a '#', which it thinks is a preprocessor directive but is wrong for python programmers trying to write an indented comment).

So vim also includes a more advanced indentation mode, filetype indentation, which allows flexible indentation rules on a per-language/filetype basis and is the preferred indentation mode for most people (even for C-like languages). If you do use filetype indentation, it's best to turn off smartindent (otherwise it can interfere with the filetype indentation, like moving all comment lines to column 0 in python files).

Personally, I always have autoindent on, use filetype when available, and never use smartindent. My .vimrc includes:

```
set autoindent " doesn't interfere with filetype indents, and is useful for text  
if has("autocmd")  
  " Enable file type detection and indentation  
  filetype plugin indent on  
  set nosmartindent  
endif
```

I imagine there's something you could do to have smartindent turned on only when filetype indenting doesn't exist for a filetype, if you're editing that many different C-like languages with no filetype indentation available.

Comment: you could cut down the insert mode map by a character by saying `imap <Home> <ESC>I` instead of `^i`

Answer (score 9):

Here’s what I have in my `.vimrc`. This maps <kbd>Home</kbd> to move to the beginning of the
text if you are anywhere in the line, and column 0 if you are at the beginning
of the text.

```
function ExtendedHome()
    let column = col('.')
    normal! ^
    if column == col('.')
        normal! 0
    endif
endfunction
noremap <silent> <Home> :call ExtendedHome()<CR>
inoremap <silent> <Home> <C-O>:call ExtendedHome()<CR>
```

**Note:** I am using a keyboard layout that maps <kbd>Home</kbd> to <kbd>Alt Gr</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>, that why I’m using this. If you have to leave the letter field of your keyboard to reach <kbd>Home</kbd>, you should probably go to normal mode instead.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use `_` in Normal mode to go to the first non-whitespace character of the current line. You can also use a count with this motion.

```
_  <underscore>     [count] - 1 lines downward,
                    on the first non-blank character linewise.
```

Answer (score 1):

Try pressing `0` (also see `:help 0`)

also, this might help:

```
:imap <C-Home> <esc>0a
```