# How do I go to the beginning of a line AFTER the indentation in VIM?

Tags: vim, vi

I know that pressing `0` will get back to the beginning of the line. But how would I get to the beginning of the line AFTER the indentation?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referencing another post:

[Pressing "Home" in Vim on an Indented Line](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2035799/pressing-home-in-vim-on-an-indented-line)

I think the answer you're looking for us to use the `^` character.

Comment: On some keyboards, we can use underscore `_` to reach to the beginning of the line and `g_` to jump to the last character of it.